# When converting from kg to stones and pounds

Tags: c++

Ok so when i input my weight in kg in gives me the correct output for stones but my pounds weight is off.

suppose 2.2 pounds is a kg 
and 14lbs is a stone

its supposed to give you weight in stones and the decimal in pounds, my stone is good but the pounds is way off any help heres the script

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//declarations
const float LBS_PER_KG=2.2;
const float LBS_PER_STONE=14;
const float STONE_PER_KG=6.36;

int main()
{

float weightInKG;
float weightInSTONE;
float weightInLBS;

cout <<"enter a measurement in Kilograms";
cin >> weightInKG;

weightInSTONE = static_cast<int>(weightInSTONE*LBS_PER_KG/LBS_PER_STONE);
weightInSTONE = weightInKG/STONE_PER_KG;
weightInLBS = weightInKG / LBS_PER_KG;
cout <<weightInKG<<"KG = "<<weightInSTONE<<"Stones and"
  <<weightInLBS<<"Pounds";
cout <<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of desired output vs actual output.

Comment: C++ program is not a script.

Comment: An ouput should be 7 stones and 7 pounds where as im getting 7.53 stones and 7.53 pounds.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation of `weightInLBS` is wrong. You have to multiply instead of divide

```
weightInLBS = weightInKG * LBS_PER_KG; // [lbs] = [kg] * ([lbs] / [kg])
```

Maybe to avoid some problems for further changes to the program you should initialize your variables with zero

```
float weightInKG = 0;
float weightInSTONE = 0;
float weightInLBS = 0;
```

For you question in the comment if you want just want to dispaly the value after decimal separator of your stone value in pounds you should use this calculation

```
weightInLBS = (weightInSTONE - static_cast<int>(weightInSTONE)) * LBS_PER_STONE;
// cut off the value before decimal separator and convert it to LBS
```

and this to display the result

```
cout <<weightInKG<<"KG = "<<static_cast<int>(weightInSTONE)<<"Stones and"<<weightInLBS<<"Pounds"<<endl;
```

Comment: so that seemed to work better now when i enter my kilograms it gives me the weight of the kilograms in stones and in pounds, instead this has to be in stones and the decimals in lbs. so if i input 47.9 kg i get 7.53 out and i need that .53 in pounds and rounded.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: so with all of the changes i get the right out put of 7 stones but i cant stop getting 0 pounds

Comment: with my code you won't get 0 pounds. There should be 7.xx pounds